# pywhatkit - not very effective for me, what i am doing wrong?

Tags: python, whatsapp

im building my first program so please if you see any big mistake on my coding please let me know, im making my own AirBnb CRM with pywhatkit to automate a message to be send every morning to my guests, i created this function to test the pywhatkit effectiveness before implementing it, and its not working very well and not sure what i am doing wrong, everything works, except that the message is written on the "text to be send" field on the whatsapp conversation.... but its not send (from 30 different tests i made, only 13 messages where send successfully)

```
import pywhatkit as pwt
import time
import mysql.connector

def Whatsapp():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "########",
    database = "########",)
    
    my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
    x="SELECT nombre, celular FROM clientes WHERE checkin <= CURDATE() AND checkout > CURDATE()"
    my_cursor.execute(x)
    numbers=my_cursor.fetchall()
    for result in numbers:
        name = (result[0])
        number = (result[1])
        text = "Hello" +name+ " Good morning, how was everything in your room?"
        pwt.sendwhatmsg_instantly(number, text, wait_time=60, tab_close=True)
        time.sleep(60)
        print("Message to ", name, "Send")
    mydb.close()
```

i placed long wait and sleep time because i saw on several posts that this could be the issue, also, when im running this function i leave my computer by itself until its done (mouse and keyboard)

Comment: Code reviews are better siuted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Are you using several monitors? For me it was working to disconnect all monitors (instead of one). I think pywhatkit has problems with multiple monitors connected.

Comment: No, im not using several monitors, thanks for your answer